# Sitecore how to select items by last update user name value

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Hello I need to select items in content tree but with condition to item statistic section, filed "Updated By"

```
fast:/sitecore/content//*[@__username = 'sitecore\user']
```

What @ variable I need to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fast:/sitecore/content//*[@__updated by = 'sitecore\user']